# powershell sending multiple parameter to a external command

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am trying to run a external exe from a powershell script.

This exe wants 4 parameters.

I have been trying every combo of invoke-item, invoke-command, & 'C:\program files\mycmd.exe myparam', made a shortcut in C:\ to get rid of the spaces in the path.

I can make it work with one parameter, but not with more. I get various errors.

To sum up, how do you send 4 parameters to an exe?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's best if shown in longhand. Once you see what's going on, you can shorten it down by just using commas between each argument.

```
$arg1 = "filename1"
$arg2 = "-someswitch"
$arg3 = "C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt"
$arg4 = "-yetanotherswitch"

$allArgs = @($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4)

& "C:\Program Files\someapp\somecmd.exe" $allArgs
```

... shorthand:

```
& "C:\Program Files\someapp\somecmd.exe" "filename1", "-someswitch", "C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt", "-yetanotherswitch"
```

Comment: Watch out with `& 'C:\program files\someapp\somecmd.exe" -arg $allArgs` - the `-arg` is unnecessary unless you were intending to pass `-arg` itself as a parameter to somecmd.exe.

Comment: Yeah, for whatever reason I referred to this today, and noticed that the line of code with the -arg in it didn't even work! Oops/removed.

Comment: I think the ( ... ) are missing from the last line: & "somecmd.exe" ("filename1", "-some...")

Answer (score 12):

In the easy case, passing arguments to a native exe is as simple as using a built-in command:

```
PS> ipconfig /allcompartments /all
```

You can run into problems when you specify a full path to an EXE and that path contains spaces.  For example if PowerShell sees this:

```
PS> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\sn.exe -k .\pubpriv.snk
```

It interprets the command to be "C:\Program" and "Files\Microsoft" as the first parameter, "SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\sn.exe" as the second parameter, etc. The simple solution is to put the path in a string use the invocation operator `&` to invoke the command named by the path e.g.:

```
PS> & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\sn.exe' -k .\pubpriv.snk
```

The next area we run into problems with is when the arguments are complex and/or use characters that PowerShell interprets specially e.g.:

```
PS> sqlcmd -v user="John Doe" -Q "select '$(user)' as UserName"
```

This doesn't work and we can debug this by using a tool from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) called `echoargs.exe` which shows you exactly how the native EXE receives the arguments from PowerShell.

```
PS> echoargs -v user="John Doe" -Q "select '$(user)' as UserName"
The term 'user' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, ...
<snip>

Arg 0 is <-v>
Arg 1 is <user=John Doe>
Arg 2 is <-Q>
Arg 3 is <select '' as UserName>
```

Note that with Arg3 `$(user)` is interpreted & evaluated by PowerShell and results in an empty string.  You can fix this problem and a good number of similar issues by using single quotes instead of double qoutes unless you really need PowerShell to evaluate a variable e.g.:

```
PS> echoargs -v user="John Doe" -Q 'select "$(user)" as UserName'
Arg 0 is <-v>
Arg 1 is <user=John Doe>
Arg 2 is <-Q>
Arg 3 is <select $(user) as UserName>
```

If all else fails, use a here string and Start-Process like so:

```
PS> Start-Process echoargs -Arg @'
>> -v user="John Doe" -Q "select '$(user)' as UserName"
>> '@ -Wait -NoNewWindow
>>
Arg 0 is <-v>
Arg 1 is <user=John Doe>
Arg 2 is <-Q>
Arg 3 is <select '$(user)' as UserName>
```

Note if you are using PSCX 1.2 you will need to prefix Start-Process like so - `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Start-Process` to use PowerShell's built-in Start-Process cmdlet.

Comment: Hm; seeing this makes me wonder again: Is there a good reason for keeping the PSCX versions of cmdlets that PowerShell v2 includes? Get-Random tripped me up a few times due to its completely different semantics.

Comment: No there isn't.  So we have moved the three cmdlets that have name collisions into a separate module in PSCX 2.0 (Pscx.Deprecated.psd1).  There is a 2.0 beta available for download but because it is module based it works only on PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: I just noticed this: [PowerShell and external commands done right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/). Nearly identical advice.

Comment: @ChristopherGalpin Link is broken, now at https://web.archive.org/web/20180317092333/http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/