# Send array values to the next line script, and run the script. Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to pass arguments to a next line script from PowerShell array.

Ex:

```
$array = @('a','b','c') # This can keep increasing. 

cobertura-merge -o coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml $array[0] $array[1] $array[2]
```

Can someone please let me know, how to accomplish this if there are `n` no.of elements in the array?

Raag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store actually a complex value in variable. So you have to first join and then split it

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    $val = @('a','b','c') -join ";"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=paramaeters;]$val"

- pwsh: | 
    $paramaeters = '$(paramaeters)'.split(";")

    cobertura-merge -o coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml @paramaeters
```

Passing array should be fine as it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2137427/2347999)

Please be awate that it will work if you do both steps inside the same job. Otherwise you need yo use output variables.

Please change `$parameter` to `@parameters` to use [splatting arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7#splatting-with-arrays)